# How to join 2 tables with getting all rows from left table and only matching ones in right

Tags: python, sql, django, django-rest-framework

Table 1

[image]

Table 2

[image]

Table2.plan_selected shows what plan did the user choose.

Eg: The user with user_id=4 in Table2 choose the id = 2 plan from Table1.

I want to get all the rows from Table1 and only matching rows from Table2 for a particular `user_id`.

The expected result is like this.

I want to fetch all the rows of Table1 and only the selected plan from Table2 for a **particular user_id lets say 4.**

The expected result will be like this:

id    name                 plan*type        plandetails                     requestper*month   price    is*deleted plan*selected

1   EXECUTIVE   MONTHLY {1000 MAY REQUSTS}  1000                 50     0          NULL

2   BASIC           MONTHLY {500 MAY REQUSTS}   1000                 25    0           2

3   FREEEE          MONTHLY {10 MAY REQUSTS}            1000                 0            0              NULL

4   EXECUTIVE   YEARLY           {1000 MAY REQUSTS} 1000                 500       0               NULL

5   BASIC            YEARLY         {500 MAY REQUSTS}   1000                250    0              NULL

6   FREEEE         YEARLY            {10 MAY REQUSTS}   1000                   0    0                  NULL

What I have tried to do was use a simple left join.

`select plans.id, name, plan_details, plan_type, request_per_month, price,is_deleted, plan_selected from SubscriptionsPlans as plans left join SubscriptionsOrder as orders on plans.id=orders.plan_selected where orders.user_id = 4`

These are my 2 models. ORM queryset or SQL query will help

```
class SubscriptionsPlans(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    plan_type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    plan_details = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    request_per_month = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.FloatField()
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class SubscriptionsOrder(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(
        AppUser,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL
    )
    plan_selected = models.ForeignKey(SubscriptionsPlans, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    billing_info = models.IntegerField()
```

Comment: Share your *models*.

Comment: Just need the quesy, Not in ORM. @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: why is this taged Django RF then?

Comment: Mistake. Removed.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I have added the models. Can you help with ORM query

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Answer (score 0):

You can query with:

```
SubscriptionsPlans.objects.filter(subscriptionsorder__user_id=4)
```

This will list all `SubscriptionPlans` for which there is a `SubscriptionOrder` with `4` as `user_id`.

Comment: In the query I also wanted the field `plan_selected` from table `SubscriptionsOrder` . But with this I only get rows from `SubscriptionsPlans` only. right?